# Redefining footnote reference

Tags: footnotes

Need to add a reference to the following customized footnote definition:

```
 \documentclass[a4paper,10pt]{article}

\usepackage{hyperref}
\hypersetup{
    colorlinks=true,
    citecolor={black},
    linkcolor={black},
    urlcolor={blue},
    pdfborder={0 0 0},
}


\usepackage{manyfoot}
\newfootnote{B}
\makeatletter
\def\sfootnote#1{\ifx\protect\@typeset@protect
    \Footnotemark{*}\FootnotetextB{*}{#1}%
  \else
    \relax
  \fi
}

\begin{document}
\tableofcontents

\newpage
\section[abc]{abc\sfootnote{cde}}

text\footnote{foot}
\end{document}
```

This will produce the footnote for the section **abc**, but when clicking on it, will not point to the footnote **cde** but to the first page.

Any idea how this feature could be also supported in the above definition?

Comment: Where is `hyperref` coming in here? In addition, `\makeatother` is desperately needed otherwise it screws up the tex run

Comment: Not really, above code works for me

Comment: It's known that `hyperref` can't behave well with footnotes.

Comment: But isn't there a way to EXPLICITLY set where to ref to? Smth like \Footnoteref (since there is \Footnotemark)

Comment: @schmi Can you explain what you want to do with all that?

Comment: I want to have a footnote (symbolic) which will not "interfere" with the numbered footnotes and still be "clickable"

Answer (score 1):

This works, but as already mentioned `hyperref` doesn't play well with packages it doesn't know how to patch itself into, such as `manyfoot`.

Note you will need to run LaTeX more than once, to resolve the cross references correctly.

I extended your example, to make a better test.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,10pt]{article}

\usepackage{hyperref}
\hypersetup{
    colorlinks=true,
    citecolor={black},
    linkcolor={black},
    urlcolor={blue},
    pdfborder={0 0 0}
}


\usepackage{manyfoot}
\newfootnote{B}
\newcounter{footB}
\makeatletter
\def\sfootnote#1{\ifx\protect\@typeset@protect
    \stepcounter{footB}%
    \hyperlink{fn:B\thefootB}{\Footnotemark{{*}}}%
    \FootnotetextB{*}{\Hy@raisedlink{\hypertarget{fn:B\thefootB}{}}#1}%
  \else
    \relax
  \fi
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\tableofcontents

\newpage
\section[abc]{abc\sfootnote{cde}}

text\footnote{foot}

\newpage
\section[abc2]{abc2\sfootnote{cde2}}

text2\footnote{foot2}


\end{document}
```

Comment: If I click on the sfootnote, document jumps to toc - ?!

Comment: does not work, jums to the first page, as was before - add the following after \begin{document} and before \tableofcontents statements to see that:

asdasda
\newpage

Comment: It works for me, using xelatex in TeXLve on Windows. It's possible the behaviour depends on the TeX engine (xelatex, pdflatex, Lua, etc)